# tensorflow sparse_to_dense function, output_shape argument

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement unpooling as described in http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/html/Noh_Learning_Deconvolution_Network_ICCV_2015_paper.html, using max_pool_with_argmax and  sparse_to_dense. but the sparse_to_dense function seems only takes scalar values as the output_shape.
for example, I wrote this script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
unpooled=tf.sparse_to_dense(sparse_indices=[0,1,3],output_shape=[3,4],sparse_values=[4,5,6])
sess=tf.Session()
[unpol]=sess.run([unpooled])
print(unpol)
```

it will raise error gose:
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: output_shape has incorrect number of elements: 2 should be: 1

So is this a bug or I'm using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The unpooled line should be:

```
unpooled=tf.sparse_to_dense(sparse_indices=[0,1,3],output_shape=[4],sparse_values=[4,5,6])

: [4,5,0,6]
```

because the maximum index is 3 which means you have 4 values.